# Why do goggle lenses have "posts?"

Tags: mountain-bike, glasses

I recently acquired a set of MTB goggles. Both the lens it came with and an alternate lens I purchased claim to have "posts," which I understand to be two small hourglass shapes protruding outward from the lens, one on each side of my face. If I have the nomenclature wrong, please tell me.

The image below (borrowed from [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/18969/33084)) shows "posts" on it, too, although that's not the brand I have. Knowing that it's a feature on competing models makes me all the more certain it has a significant purpose.

[image: Goggle picture]

What are they for? Changing out the lens? Protection? Something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some environments are much dirtier than others, and goggles are continually getting soiled.
Sometimes a large amount suddenly gets deposited, effectively blinding the rider.

One solution is to have a thin plastic sheet attached across the goggles.
*It* gets dirty, but not the goggle lens itself, and it can be pulled off and replaced.

Even better, to avoid the time required to apply another cover, a stack of them can be installed, and only the dirty top layer is removed each time.

> Tear-offs are thin plastic sheets that are installed onto the goggles and torn off when they get too dirty to see through.
> They protect goggles from scratching and ensure a safer and uninterrupted riding experience.
> They’re attached to pegs on goggles with only the top tear-off’s tab hanging out on the left for easy reach and tearing.
>
> — [What are Goggle Tear-Offs and How to Install Them - Risk Racing](https://riskracing.com/blogs/news/helmet-tear-offs-and-how-to-install-them)

Comment: These are in Motocross as well, and might be referred to as "tearoffs"

Comment: that sounds like a sure way to loose some of those "tearoffs" along the trail, though

Comment: @njzk2, they're supposed to be one-use disposable.  But it's far worse than that, especially in the automobile racing world: [Visor tear-off which spoiled Leclerc's race was Verstappen's - Ferrari · RaceFans](https://www.racefans.net/2022/08/28/visor-tear-off-which-spoiled-leclercs-race-was-verstappens-ferrari/)

Comment: It sounds like a recipe for plastic litter all over the trails

Comment: @ChrisH the sport is moving towards "roll-offs" for this very reason. There's a continuous roll of plastic on one side of the google, and you pull a draw string on the other to roll the dirt plastic to the other side and fresh plastic over the lens.

Comment: @ChrisH here's an example of a roll-of goggle https://www.100percent.com/products/armega-forecast-film-system

Comment: @PaulH a much nicer solution